# How to switch Airplane Mode Off when you don't have Wi-Fi (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, wired

Every previous question about Airplane Mode -problems I could found related to Wi-Fi. However, my old Fujitsu Amilo Pi 3560 -laptop doesn't even have a working Wi-Fi adapter. It has been disabled / removed a long time ago and I work only with a wired connection.

Now, Airplane Mode got suddenly switched On ->

That disabled also the wired connection (Activation of network connection failed) ->

1) I do not have physical switch for Airplane Mode in my laptop

2) Neither do I have Airplane-symbol in keyboard

3) I do have that radiomast-symbol (in F1), but that doesn't make anything 
(as I haven't got the WiFi)

4) I can't access the screen with Airplane Mode -switch in Settings either as it doesn't open the Wi-Fi selections at all (No Wi-Fi Adapter Found)

5) Network - Wired doesn't have any selection about Airplane Mode

I have tried to find terminal-commands for switching Airplane Mode off, but failed so far.

And indeed based on the manual of this 10-year-old laptop - it does not have in-built Airplane Mode at all...

What should I do next? I have an alternative computer available for now but that is very temporary.

Comment: Please edit yourquestion to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Which terminal commands I should run?

Comment: rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

Comment: And for lspci :
06:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)

Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172]

roller [10ec:8172]

Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se

Kernel modules: rtl8192se

Comment: Sorry for difficult format for reading. I can't get the line changes to work properly while writing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
>   [10ec:8172] roller [10ec:8172] Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se Kernel
>   modules: rtl8192se

It appears that your wireless card is not inactive and is not removed. You can disable its driver and therefore stop Airplane Mode permanently by unloading and blacklisting its driver:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8192se
echo "blacklist rtl8192se"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Are those commands all written in one line or is that 4 separate commands?

And thank you for the help for an Ubuntu novice!!!!

Comment: Separate I see. Seemed to work... At least Airplane Mode went off - now I only to get Wired Connection to work again...

Comment: Please try: `sudo service network-manager restart` and see if it works. If not, try a reboot.

Comment: Ran the service network -command, rebooted thrice already.

No help - still saying : "Activation of network connection failed"

Comment: I suggest that you start a new question regarding the ethernet and include the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` I have successfully answered your Airplane Mode question. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour